# My solution to the minimum size subarray sum problem passes 13/15 cases, but I cannot seem to find the bug in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

For this Leetcode question:

Given an array of n positive integers and a positive integer s, find the minimal length of a contiguous subarray of which the sum ≥ s. If there isn't one, return 0 instead.

My code works for almost every case, yet Leetcode rejects my answer. I cannot for the life of me figure out the bug in my code. Could you guys help me out? Thank you in advance. I have opted to use the two pointer method for this problem.

This is the case that does not pass:

```
s = 697439
[5334,6299,4199,9663,8945,3566,9509,3124,6026,6250,7475,5420,9201,9501,38,5897,4411,6638,9845,161,9563,8854,3731,5564,5331,4294,3275,1972,1521,2377,3701,6462,6778,187,9778,758,550,7510,6225,8691,3666,4622,9722,8011,7247,575,5431,4777,4032,8682,5888,8047,3562,9462,6501,7855,505,4675,6973,493,1374,3227,1244,7364,2298,3244,8627,5102,6375,8653,1820,3857,7195,7830,4461,7821,5037,2918,4279,2791,1500,9858,6915,5156,970,1471,5296,1688,578,7266,4182,1430,4985,5730,7941,3880,607,8776,1348,2974,1094,6733,5177,4975,5421,8190,8255,9112,8651,2797,335,8677,3754,893,1818,8479,5875,1695,8295,7993,7037,8546,7906,4102,7279,1407,2462,4425,2148,2925,3903,5447,5893,3534,3663,8307,8679,8474,1202,3474,2961,1149,7451,4279,7875,5692,6186,8109,7763,7798,2250,2969,7974,9781,7741,4914,5446,1861,8914,2544,5683,8952,6745,4870,1848,7887,6448,7873,128,3281,794,1965,7036,8094,1211,9450,6981,4244,2418,8610,8681,2402,2904,7712,3252,5029,3004,5526,6965,8866,2764,600,631,9075,2631,3411,2737,2328,652,494,6556,9391,4517,8934,8892,4561,9331,1386,4636,9627,5435,9272,110,413,9706,5470,5008,1706,7045,9648,7505,6968,7509,3120,7869,6776,6434,7994,5441,288,492,1617,3274,7019,5575,6664,6056,7069,1996,9581,3103,9266,2554,7471,4251,4320,4749,649,2617,3018,4332,415,2243,1924,69,5902,3602,2925,6542,345,4657,9034,8977,6799,8397,1187,3678,4921,6518,851,6941,6920,259,4503,2637,7438,3893,5042,8552,6661,5043,9555,9095,4123,142,1446,8047,6234,1199,8848,5656,1910,3430,2843,8043,9156,7838,2332,9634,2410,2958,3431,4270,1420,4227,7712,6648,1607,1575,3741,1493,7770,3018,5398,6215,8601,6244,7551,2587,2254,3607,1147,5184,9173,8680,8610,1597,1763,7914,3441,7006,1318,7044,7267,8206,9684,4814,9748,4497,2239]
```

```
def minSubArrayLen(s: int, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    if s in nums:
        return 1
    if sum(nums)<s or nums==[]:
        return 0
    
    ptr1=0
    ptr2=len(nums)
    
    while True:
        if(sum(nums[ptr1:ptr2])<s):
            break
        else:
            if nums[ptr1]>nums[ptr2-1]:
                ptr2-=1
            else:
                ptr1+=1
    
    return len(nums[ptr1:ptr2])+1
```

Comment: Do you know the cases it does not pass?

Comment: Yes. I just updated my post to show the case. Thank you.

Comment: What did you try already to find the error in the code? You might want to read this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: [2, 4, 1, 4] with s=6 is a minimal example. This isn't a problem you can solve with a greedy approach, although it does produce the right answers often.

Comment: The problem seems to be your algorithm.  You should check [this algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-length-subarray-sum-greater-given-value/).  Also, FYI: `sum(nums[ptr1:ptr2])<s)` in the loop is needlessly inefficient when you're only updating a sum by adding or removing a point from an end (though unrelated to why your algorithm doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

```
def minSubArrayLen(s: int, nums: List[int]) -> int:
   total = left = 0
   result = len(nums) + 1
   for right, n in enumerate(nums):
       total += n
       while total >= s:
           result = min(result, right - left + 1)
           total -= nums[left]
           left += 1
   return result if result <= len(nums) else 0
```

The way you are using the TWO POINTER will work fine only if we have to sort the array and then think of applying two-pointer as per question requirement.
Since here we don't need to sort the array as per ques. The above code will work fine!!✌